# Uploading images to server using ASIHTTPRequest in iphone

Tags: ios4, asihttprequest

I have to upload images to server form iphone I am using ASIHTTPRequest for this. I have set a loop for uploading seven files. But after the executing only last file is uploaded can some one point out where I am getting it wrong.

I am using the below code for uploading :

```
for (int i=1; i<8; i++) 
    {
        NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo%d.jpg", i];
        NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        [request setFile:path forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file"]];
    }

    [request startAsynchronous];
    [resultView setText:@"Uploading data..."];

My Php file code is as following : 



 <?php
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("vinay/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "vinay/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "http://serverpath" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the key called file & you need to use a queue.

Do

```
[self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
[[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];

for (int i=1; i<8; i++) 
{
    NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo%d.jpg", i];
    NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [request setFile:path forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%d", i]];
    [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
}
[[self networkQueue] go];
```

Comment: Hi I have tried your option but this time around no file is uploaded. I have also attached my php file code to the question if this is creating some problem.

Comment: I think the PHP is ok.  I think you need to use a Queue - I'll update my answer....

Comment: Getting following error "Method setNetworkQueue not found" & "Method networkQueue not found". I have added ASINetworkQueue.h file

Comment: have you added ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue; to your interface in your .h file and #import "ASINetworkQueue.h"?

Comment: & have you added @property (nonatomic, retain) ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue; in your. h
& @synthesize networkQueue; in your .m

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `request.file`, hence only the last one gets uploaded. You have to make individual requests for each file.

Or you could use `[request addFile:(id)data withFileName:(NSString *)fileName andContentType:(NSString *)contentType forKey:(NSString *)key]` to send multiple files in one request.

Comment: I have to upload several files (number of files not confirmed) now how to set request so that we can employ this with loop.