# Uploading image to server with ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, objective-c

Hi build a service for my iPhone app and need to have function that get image from the user:
Until now i used to get only text with this method:

```
string input = null;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
      input = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

How should i get the image from the post?

This is how i send the image from the iphone app:

```
imageRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[imageRequest addData:imageData withFileName:@"someFileName.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"uploadedImage"];
[imageRequest setDelegate:self];
[imageRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[imageRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload image by adding image with name. First convert UIImage object into Base64Encoding string and then send that string to server.

Download supporting files from the link  [enter link description here](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/?tag=/uiimage)

and the use these methods

```
- (NSString*) stringFromImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    if(image){
        NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        return [dataObj base64Encoding];
    } else {
        return @"";
    }
}

- (UIImage*) imageFromString:(NSString*)imageString
{
    NSData* imageData =[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:imageString];
    return [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

}
```

Also check this link for Image to string and string to image in Base64  [image conversion](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2010/03/14/Convert-image-tofrom-text-%28Base64%29.aspx)

it helps u

Comment: But i saw a lot of posts here in ASIFormDataRequest that it possible to send data

Comment: Use ASINetworkQueue class in ASIForm kit.
Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680503/uploading-images-to-server-using-asihttprequest-in-iphone


it will helps u