# Upload an image to PHP from an iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, ios, objective-c

I am uploading an image to PHP from an iPhone but in PHP the image is not visible. The image was saving in bytes.

```
  -(void)uploadMyImage:(UIImage *)img
    {
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90);
        NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        [Base64 initialize];
        [urlString appendFormat:@"image=%@",[Base64 encode:data]];
          NSString *baseurl = @"http://projectleads.info/spirits/images/imageupload1.php"  ;
        NSData *postData = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
        [urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        [connection start];
        }
```

```
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        resData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        [resData appendData:data];
    }
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resData
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
```

And my php code is

```
<?php
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
     if(empty($base))
    {
        echo 'No data';
    }
    else
    {
    echo $base;
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
        // print($binary);
    //$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);
    $dbser='localhost';  
    $dbuser='spirit';
    $dbpwd='123456';
    $dbname='spirit';
       $db= mysql_connect($dbser,$dbuser,$dbpwd);
     $dbcon=mysql_select_db($dbname);
     function generate_chars()
    {
        $num_chars = 4; //max length of random chars
        $i = 0;
        $my_keys = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //keys to be chosen from
        $keys_length = strlen($my_keys);
        $url  = "";
        while($i<$num_chars)
        {
            $rand_num = mt_rand(1, $keys_length-1);
            $url .= $my_keys[$rand_num];
            $i++;
        }
        return $url;
    }

     function isUnique($chars)
    {
        //check the uniqueness of the chars
        global $link;
        $q = "SELECT * FROM `url` WHERE `randname`='".$chars."'";
        $r = mysql_query($q, $link);
        //echo mysql_num_rows($r); die();
        if( mysql_num_rows($r)>0 ): 
            return false;
        else: 
            return true;
        endif;
    }

     $chars = generate_chars();
     while( !isUnique($chars) )
     {
            $chars = generate_chars();
     }
    $query=mysql_query("insert into url (randname) values ('".$chars."')");
    $test=$chars.".jpg";
    $file = fopen($test, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'success';
    echo '<img src=test.jpg>';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone :

Check here [How to upload Image on PHP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394647/uploading-image-to-server-with-asiformdatarequest/14395038#14395038)

Also this [Upload Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680503/uploading-images-to-server-using-asihttprequest-in-iphone)

And For converting UIImage into String using Base64 Ecoding use [Base64 Ecoding Method](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2010/03/14/Convert-image-tofrom-text-%28Base64%29.aspx)

I hope this will helps You

Comment: final string response are coming in the formate of base 64 and image also saving in server but it is not visible.

Comment: decode Base64 String into UIImage it gives u same Image that u uploaded I think

Comment: No i am not decoded base 64 string to uiimage the string response are coming from server

Comment: I think your client side coding in now working fine now. There is a problem on Server side.

Comment: and what they receive in response??

Comment: same response what we are getting

Comment: I have edited my ans and provides u two more methods for conversion of Image to string and string to Image.

Convert that received String into UIImage by using that method and save that Image.

Comment: other wise using that code please send image as manually and i will check it in my server please dont mind....i am trying it from 2 days onwards

Comment: Hi satish please do some thing

Comment: I have provided all methods for uploading Image. But what problem u r facing now i dont known. Pls let me know ur whats problem u r facing in uploading image in details

Comment: i uploaded image in the formate of base 64 and image also saving at server like 24kb,64kb.... but the image is not visible..is there any mistakes in my code pls check it.

Comment: is Image is not saved on Server Side?

Comment: it is saving but not visible

Comment: It means ur server side decoding is not correct to create image from String.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is just fine, the problem is in the base 64 encoding. I have successfully uploaded an image with your code, do the following to correctly encode the data.

Copy and paste this method in your code (taken from [Creating a base-64 string from NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006823/creating-a-base-64-string-from-nsdata))

```
- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*) theData {
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Now to get the encoded string do

```
NSString *encodedString = [[self base64forData:data] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Append the encoded string as follows

```
[urlString appendFormat:@"image=%@", encodedString];
```